# aws - upgrade autoscale base AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, aws-code-deploy

I have setup a `HA` architecture using `Autoscaling`, `load balancer` , `code deploy`.

I have a `base-image` through which `autoscale` launch any new instance. This `base-image` will get outdated with time and I may have to upgrade it.

My confusion is how can I provision this `base AMI` to install desire version of packages ? and How will I provision the already `in-service` instances ?

For-example - Currently my `base AMI` have `php5.3` but if in future I need `PHP5.5` then how can I provision `in-service` fleet of `EC2 instances` and as well as `base AMI`

I have **Chef as provisioning server**. So how should I proceed for above problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AMI that an instance uses is determined through the launch configuration when the instance boots. Therefore, the only way to change the AMI of an instance is to terminate it and launch it again.

In an autoscaling scenario, this is relatively easy: update the launch configuration of the autoscaling group to use the new AMI and terminate all instances you want to upgrade. You can do a rolling upgrade by terminating the instances one-by-one.

When your autoscaling group scales up and down frequently and it's OK for you to have multiple versions of the AMI in your autoscaling group, you can just update the launch configuration and wait. Every time the autoscaling process kicks in and a new instance is launched, the new AMI is used. When the autoscaling group has the right 'termination policy' ("OldestInstance", for example), every time the autoscaling process scales down, an instance running the old AMI will be terminated.
So, let's say your have 4 instances running. You update the launch config to use a new AMI. After 4 scale-up actions and 4 scale-down actions, all instances are running the new AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Autoscale has a feature called Launch Configuration, which includes the ability to pass in userdata, which will get executed at launch time.  The userdata can be saved within Launch Configuration so that you can automate the process.

I have never worked with Chef and I'm sure there is a Chef-centric way of doing this, but the quick and dirty would be to use userdata.

Your userdata script (i.e. BASH) would then include the necessary sudo apt-get remove / install commands (assuming Ubuntu OS).

The documentation for this is here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/APIReference/API_CreateLaunchConfiguration.html

> UserData The user data to make available to the launched EC2
>   instances. For more information, see Instance Metadata and User Data
>   in the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud User Guide.
>
> At this time, launch configurations don't support compressed (zipped)
>   user data files.
>
> Type: String
>
> Length constraints: Minimum length of 0. Maximum length of 21847.
>
> Pattern: [\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF\r\n\t]*
>
> Required: No

Comment: Thanks .. let me go through it and will let you know here .. thanks